# Написать программу, которая возвращает список который содержит все имена

Tags: python

```
    capital_latter = []
    s = "qwer tyui Oper asdf Ghjf Klui Qzxcv".split(" ")
    for i in s:
        if i >= "A" and i <= "Z":
            capital_latter.append(i)
print(i, capital_latter)
```

Как написать программу, которая возвращает список который содержит все имена.

Я думаю, можна просто искать в строке слова с большой буквы и выводить

Comment: Что значит 'содержит все имена'? Имена внутри предложений - это понятно. А 'все имена' ?

Comment: @MrSlimny ну просто все имена

Comment: `capital_letter = [i for i in s if i[0].isupper()]`

Comment: @Bohdan имеете ввиду все имена в мире? Такого функционала нет ни в одном языке.